# Jenkins: Reuse Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I’ve got a lot of multibranch pipeline projects that use a same kind of Docker container. Is it possible to reuse that Docker container over multiple jobs? I want to do this to preserve storage space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended, as you might get some unexpected side-effects from previous runs.

If you want to save space, make sure to clean up the containers once they exist using either `--rm` option which removes the container once existing:

```
agent {
        docker {
            image ...
            args '--rm'
        }
    }
```

or by running `docker system prune --volumes -f` which will do a clean up of unused docker images and containers and volumes.

Comment: Hi @yamenk, thanks for the reply, would it be advisable to add the prune command to the `post` section of my Jenkinsfile?